# query last logged on date for multiple users

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

I'm writing a script that needs to query when several domain users last logged on to a machine. I thought I could do it with the last accessed date of \docs and settings\username but our backup tool scuppered that plan.

Then I looked at using WMI_UserProfile but that only queries local profiles. So that led me to WNI_NetworkLoginProfile but I seem to be able to only get the logon date for the logged on user. Is it possible to query last logon date for multiple users using WNI_NetworkLoginProfile or is there something else I can query?

```
On Error Resume Next

Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = WshNetwork.ComputerName

strDayOfMonth = Right("0" & Day(Date()),2)
strMonth = Right("0" & Month(Date()),2)
strYear = Right (Year(Date()),4)
strDate = strDayOfMonth & "/" & strMonth & "/" & strYear

oLast = DateAdd("d", -60, strDate)

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Global = True   
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM|NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM|NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE|NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile")

For Each objItem in colItems
dtmAccessTime = objItem.LastLogon
strReturn = WMIDateStringToDate(dtmAccessTime)
strUsers = objItem.Name
Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strUsers)
If colMatches.Count < 1 Then
    strfolder = objFolder.Name
    Wscript.Echo objItem.Name & " " & strReturn
End If
Next

' Format Time and Date
 Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmStart)
WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmStart, 5, 2) & "/" & _
    Mid(dtmStart, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmStart, 4) _
        & " " & Mid (dtmStart, 9, 2) & ":" & _
            Mid(dtmStart, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmStart, _
                13, 2))
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing using the commandline tool `wmic` as:

```
C:\> WMIC PATH Win32_NetworkLoginProfile GET Name,LastLogon
```

shows me the data for all users on my machine. This makes me wonder whether this is locked to whether you have administrative rights or not. On a Windows Vista/7/2008 box, this may also mean that User Access Control is preventing you see all the data.

Try forcing your script to run as an administator.

Comment: thanks, running that returns all the user profiles and dates. For some reason my script doesn't

Comment: Post your script up so others can take a look at it.